# Object instanciation by ArrayList.add()?

Tags: java

In the following example, the float value 0.5 is accessible outside of the code block in which it was add()ed:

```
ArrayList<Float> myFloatArray = new ArrayList<Float>();
{
    myFloatArray.add( 0.5f );
}
// Data is accessible out of the block
```

Can someone explain what happens in terms of object instanciation ? Why isn't the Float object destroyed when we leave the block it was defined ? Is it equivalent to writing

```
myFloatArray.add( new Float(0.5f) );
```

The reason I am asking this is that I would like to add a time information to each float value. I thought about creating a class that would enable me to write:

```
myDataPointArray.add( new dataPoint( new GregorianCalendar(2011, 11, 11), 0.5f );
```

However, (as expected), the ArrayList is empty outside of the block the data was add()ed. I tried to make my class immutable, as I believe it may help, but it doesn't work any better. Can someone point me the right place where this behaviour is documented ? I wasn't able to find it and I think its goes beyond this ArrayList example.

Comment: Items created on the heap (i.e. via `new`) don't have lifetimes controlled by scope (i.e. program block).  So I don't understand why your second example is causing a problem (I wouldn't expect the list to be empty).  Could you create a self-contained test case (see http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All objects added to your `ArrayList` will reside in memory as long as the `ArrayList` is still in use. 
As for you second question, the `myDataPointArray` will never loose any object you have added to it unless you remove the object from the list.

Are you sure you are not re-assigning a new `ArrayList` object to `myDataPointArray` somewhere else after the `add` operation?

Comment: **Are you sure you are not re-assigning a new ArrayList object to myDataPointArray somewhere else after the add operation?** Yes, I was. I feel bad. But I also learned something about heap allocation. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't the Float object destroyed when we leave the block it was defined?

Because in Java objects are allocated on the heap. There is no concept like a stack allocation. As long as anything still has a reference to the object (`myFloatArray` has one in this case) the object isn't eligible for garbage collections and thus subsequent destruction.

Answer (score 1):

You're arrayList shouldn't be empty outside the block and in my tests it isn't.

```
package se.wederbrand.stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class SomeArrayStuff {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<DataPoint> myDataPointArray = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
    {
      myDataPointArray.add(new DataPoint(new GregorianCalendar(2011, 11, 11), 0.5f));
    }
    System.out.println(myDataPointArray.size());
  }

  private static class DataPoint {
    private GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar;
    private float v;

    public DataPoint(GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar, float v) {
      this.gregorianCalendar = gregorianCalendar;
      this.v = v;
    }
  }
}
```

This will correctly print out 1 as that is the size of the list outside the scoop.

Comment: Yes, you are correct indeed. The value I was watching wasn't immediately after exiting the loop. Lesson learned !